# Listar na sidebar lista de Taxonomias Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

tenho a seguinte estrutura:

Custom Taxonomia Marcas de Carros

- Ford

  - Carro x
  - Carro Y
  - Carro Z
- Audi

Quero listar na sidebar todos os carros da ford cadastrados. Como posso fazer sem plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Use a função [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) para buscar o ID de Ford e [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) para listar os termos-filhos. Se a taxonomia não for `category` troque no exemplo pelo nome apropriado:

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $parent = get_term_by( 'name', 'Ford', 'category' );
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'childof' => $parent->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
    ) );
?> 
</ul>
```